# Android: SQLite Cannot bind argument at index because the index is out of range

Tags: java, android, sqlite, kotlin

I'm using an SQLite database to store items. When I call items by their ids using where clause and selection args. If I pass a selection args array with more than one item id, it crashes with error:

> Cannot bind argument at index 2 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 1 parameters.

Here is how I perform the query:

```
    override fun onCreateLoader(id: Int, args: Bundle?): Loader<Cursor> { 
    loaderId = id 
    val selectionArgs = arrayOf("2", "1")
    return CursorLoader(activity!!,
            MenuContract.ItemEntry.CONTENT_URI,
            Constants.ITEM_PROJECTION_COLUMNS,           
            MenuContract.ItemEntry._ID + "=?",  
            selectionArgs,
            null
    ) 
}
```

It works fine if the selectionArgs array contains only one id. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of selection args must match the number of **`?`**'s (placeholders). So the error is basically saying *where do I put the second argument as I've already replaced the first **`?`** (placeholder)*

It works when there is only 1 array element, because there is only 1 **`?`** (placeholder).

Perhaps you want :-

```
MenuContract.ItemEntry._ID + "=? OR " + MenuContract.ItemEntry._ID + "=?",
```

Then both arguments have a placeholder.

Comment: Thank you that worked! In my case the user can add items to favorites, and I'm storing the added items' ids in prefs so when the favorites screen opens, it fetches items based on those ids. Now, I guess, I need to form the selection string based on the number of items. This selection part is not intuitive.